# Choice of the kernel function in Gaussian Process (GP) regression when one component of the input vector is in range $[-\pi,\pi]$

Tags: normal-distribution, kernel-smoothing

I was wondering how to deal with the choice of the kernel function when one of the components of the input vector is within $[-\pi,\pi]$. This interval is circular.

My first solution has been to modify the squared exponential automatic relevance determination (ARD) function such that when the difference between two input vectors is computed the difference between the two components within $[-\pi,\pi]$ is treated in a correct way.

Do you have other suggestions?

Comment: Is the interval circular? Is $-\pi$ closer to $\pi$ than $0$?

Comment: yes, this interval is circular.